# Python Simple Class not Recognized

Tags: python

```
class Example:
values=None

s1=Example
s1.values.append(1)
s1.values.append(2)

for x in s1.values:
    print x
```

Using Python 2.7

Output:

```
line 8, in Example
    s1=Example
NameError: name 'Example' is not defined
    enter code here
```

New to python and not sure why it's not recognizing the simple class.

Comment: Fix the indentation first.

Comment: exactly what @Nuncameesquecideti said: indentation is **critical** to python code, and it's totally unclear what your code "should" do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code indentation, which is critical to the problem, is not fixed, leaving it uncertain what OP wants to do.

Comment: When you're done indenting, you could also stop trying to append to None.

Comment: ` s1=Example()` shoud be like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example for you:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []

s1 = Example()
s1.values.append(1)
s1.values.append(2)

for x in s1.values:
    print x
```

Also, I'd recommend you to follow some available [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) out there